# Client access to samba server if servers NETBIOS is not unique

Tags: networking, server, samba

I am developing an embedded Linux system and have configured a net bios name in my smb.conf - though, if I have two of these systems running on my network I cannot access either servers' shared folders because they have the same NETBIOS.

Does anyone have a solution for ensuring one's server has a unique net bios or WINS name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default value for `netbios name` is the DNS name of the machine where samba is executing (unique in your network, otherwise, you have a network problem...).  So, just leaving the parameter `netbios name` undefined should solve yout problem.

Other possibilty: use string substitution.  In that case, uyou would have in your smb.conf file something like :
`netbios name = %I` 
In this example `%I` stands for internet adress.  A complete list of subsitution varaibles can be founs here: [Official Samba doc](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html)

Hope this helps.